# sqlite attribute execute is read-only

Tags: python, exception, sqlite

I am using sqlite to create and connect to a sqlite db foo.db

When I try to do an insert into the DB. I get the following AttributeError

```
AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object attribute 'execute' is read-only
```

I can't seem to find any information on this error. Does anyone have any idea what this exception means?

I am using python 2.7 with virtualenv.

The following is the code I am trying to execute assume date is a string.

```
        username = 'user'
        pwdhash = some_hash_function()
        email = 'user@foo.com'
        date = '11/07/2011'

        g.db = sqlite3.connect('foo.db')
        cur = g.db.cursor()            
        cur.execute = ('insert into user_reg (username,pwdhash,email,initial_date)\
                        values (?,?,?,?)',
                        [username,
                         pwdhash,
                         email,
                         date])
        g.db.commit()
        g.db.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: The error means exactly what it says: you're trying to assign to an attribute that's read-only. Without seeing code, it's hard to say why that's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to modify an attribute of the cursor. You want to call a method of the cursor.

It should be

```
    cur.execute('insert into user_reg (username,pwdhash,email,initial_date)\
                    values (?,?,?,?)',
                    [username,
                     pwdhash,
                     email,
                     date])
```

Not

```
    cur.execute = ('insert ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a simple syntax error.
You are trying to set a value to the command execute while you have just to call it:
remove the '=' and it should be fine.