# python AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object attribute 'execute' is read-only while doing a SELECT

Tags: python, sqlite

i'm just trying to do a simple select and the error keeps appearing

```
def affichage_produit():
     conn=sqlite3.connect('stock.db')
     cursor=conn.cursor()
     cursor.execute=("""SELECT * FROM PRODUIT  """)
     for row in cursor.fetchall():
         print (row)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlite attribute execute is read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054582/sqlite-attribute-execute-is-read-only)